# Retrieving data from database and storing in an array

Tags: php, mysql

I want retrieve data from mysql database and store in an array. Later I would display the data in html.

Below is my code snippet:

```
select co_no from faculty_co where course_code='$course1_code';
```

The output will display a total 5 `co_no` values. I want to store this values in an array and display as dropdown menu in html using select tag.

I am new to php. Please tell me how do I retrieve and store it.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php  We're not here to teach you what is essentially basic PHP.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Storing database records into array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5366620/storing-database-records-into-array)

Comment: Read a mysql PDO manual. You have different methods for fetching data.
http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

Answer (score 0):

First off, [php.net](http://php.net) has a lot of documentation on mysql and other things and is pretty easy to understand.

Check out the documentation and examples [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php).

Comment: Generally, recommending a deprecated API is considered bad form.

Comment: @Strawberry Thanks for pointing that out. I probably should have stayed away from this one. I fixed the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm 'old school', and not much of a programmer, so I tend to do things procedurally.

I do it something like this:

```
include('path/to/connection/stateme.nts'); // the connection is a variable '$db'

$query = "my query";

$result = mysqli_query($db,$query);

$rows = array(); //initialise array

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
$rows[] = $row;
}
```

Now you can store that as a json_encoded string or just retain it as an array for later use.