# get rows from mysql in php array [its not duplicate of any other questions]

Tags: php, mysql

As i mentioned its not duplicate of other questions asked by users, in other solution peoples are getting the values and printing it in the same page. But i need to store the mysql data in php array and will pass this array to my android app.

Below is my php code to get a list of data from mysql db, now my need is to store these data in a php array so that i can send this data back to the android app who is calling this page. So how do i store the results in a php array.

```
$stmt = $linkID1->prepare("select slno,video_url,views,downloads from VideoUploads");
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($slno,$video_url,$views,$downloads);
    $stmt->fetch();
    $stmt->close();
```

here, $stmt->bind_result(), can store only 1 result at a time, so i need an array which can store all the results, then i will pass that  array to my android app.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Storing database records into array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5366620/storing-database-records-into-array)

Comment: @MdMonjurUlHasan.........Its not duplicate, there he is fetching and printing the array in the page only. But I need to just store the output in php array and send it back to my android app.

Comment: `$res = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` you can try this and then return `$res`

Answer (score 0):

You are asking two different questions so here are two different answers:

#### How to store some stuff in an array?

Since you already have these values in some variables, you can just create an array with them:

```
$arrayOfStuff = array($slno,$video_url,$views,$downloads);
```

But you may want to look at `get_result` instead of `bind_result`. You could do something like:

```
$stmt = $linkID1->prepare("select slno,video_url,views,downloads from VideoUploads");
$stmt->execute();
$arrayOfStuff = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_array();
$stmt->fetch();
$stmt->close();
```

#### How to send an array to my Android app?

Well that depends on your app. I guess you're writing an API that it will access? Does it expect you to respond with some json or xml or something? You'll probably do something like this:

```
echo json_encode($arrayOfStuff);
```

But there's really not enough information here to answer this part of your question properly.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got the solution with some googling--

```
/* Get total number of records */
$sql = "SELECT count(*) FROM VideoUploads";
$retval = $conn->query($sql);
if(! $retval )
{
  die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);
}

$rec_count = $retval->fetch_row();
$rec_count = $rec_count[0];

//getting all data from table
$sql = "SELECT * FROM VideoUploads ORDER BY slno DESC";

$retval = $conn->query($sql);
if(! $retval )
{
 die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);
}

//creating an array for response
 $response = array();

 if ($retval->num_rows > 0) {
 $response["wallpapers"] = array();
 $response["success"] = 1;
 $response["count"]= $rec_count;
 while ($row = $retval->fetch_array()) {
        // temp wallpaper array
        $wallpaper = array();
        $wallpaper["slno"] = $row["slno"];
        $wallpaper["video_url"] = "http://xxxwebsiteurlxxx/".$row["video_url"];
        $wallpaper["downloads"] = $row["downloads"];
        $wallpaper["views"] = $row["views"];


        // push all data into final response array
        array_push($response["wallpapers"], $wallpaper);
    }

    // echoing JSON response
   echo str_replace('\/','/',json_encode($response));
   //echo str_replace('\/','/',json_encode($response,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));

} else {
    // no wallpapers found
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "No Wallpapers found";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$resultdata = array();
$resultdata['data']=array();
$stmt = $linkID1->prepare("select slno,video_url,views,downloads from VideoUploads");
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($slno,$video_url,$views,$downloads);
$stmt->fetch();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
while ($myrow = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
$rowdata = array('slno'=>$myrow->slno,'video_url' => $myrow->video_url, 'views' => $myrow->views,'downloads'=>$myrow->downloads);
array_push($resultdata['data'], $rowdata);
}
$stmt->close();
?>
```